# Compilation Error with ld+json script and razor views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, schema.org

I m trying to add some schema.org stuff to my site and the razor view engine is giving me troubles.  Here is what I am trying to add to my main layout:

```
  <script type="application/ld+json"> 
        {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "http://www.example.com",
        "logo": "http://www.example.com/media.ashx/repzio-icon.png"
        }
    </script>
```

The @context is the issue here, how do I get around this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Escape it with `@@`:

**Markup**

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
        {
        "@@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@@type": "Organization",
        "url": "http://www.example.com",
        "logo": "http://www.example.com/media.ashx/repzio-icon.png"
        }
    </script>
```

**View Source**

[image: Source]